# Importing a pdf file in nextJs 13

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, next.js

I am building a portfolio site and want to add a button to download my resume. The pdf file is in the /public/resume.pdf . I want to import the file to a react component where I can the traditional `<a href=ResumePDF download>Download the resume</a>`. I'm having this error:

```
./public/resume.pdf
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
```

I assume I've to change the next config file, but don't know that. Please advice...

Edit:
This is my current next config file (next.config.mjs since I've mdx config )-

```
import remarkGfm from 'remark-gfm'
import createMDX from '@next/mdx'
 
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  pageExtensions: ['js', 'jsx', 'mdx', 'ts', 'tsx'],
}
 
const withMDX = createMDX({
  options: {
    remarkPlugins: [remarkGfm],
    rehypePlugins: [],
  },
})
 
// Merge MDX config with Next.js config
export default withMDX(nextConfig)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downloaded the file loader npm package and changed the config file as shown...

```
import remarkGfm from 'remark-gfm';
import createMDX from '@next/mdx';

/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  pageExtensions: ['js', 'jsx', 'mdx', 'ts', 'tsx'],
  webpack: (config, { isServer }) => {
    // Add a rule to handle PDF files
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.(pdf)$/,
      use: [
        {
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: {
            publicPath: '/_next/',
            name: 'static/media/[name].[hash].[ext]',
          },
        },
      ],
    });

    if (!isServer) {
      // Ensure that the file-loader is applied to the client as well
      config.resolve.fallback.fileSystem = false;
    }

    return config;
  },
};

const withMDX = createMDX({
  options: {
    remarkPlugins: [remarkGfm],
    rehypePlugins: [],
  },
});

// Merge MDX config with Next.js config
export default withMDX(nextConfig);
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me know if this helps

```
next.config.js
module.exports = {
    webpack: (config, { isServer }) => {
        config.module.rules.unshift({
            test: /pdf\.worker\.(min\.)?js/,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: "file-loader",
                    options: {
                        name: "[contenthash].[ext]",
                        publicPath: "_next/static/worker",
                        outputPath: "static/worker"
                    }
                }
            ]
        });
        return config;
    }
};
```

This works for me, you need add some loaders to the next.config.js

Daniel

Comment: I've added my current config file, pls have a look.

Comment: .@GaddMaster Please look at the updated question (config file)

Comment: Your config file has not attempted to try use what I shared, why not ?

Comment: Intention of the answer is to just show you a simple example of a loader, which is what you need, not completely implement your code and test it. Why not, because I do have have the time ! I do the best I can with the limited time I have ! That Ok with you !

Comment: The confusion was because I was using a different config file as I was using markdown and didn't know how to combine both of these. But it is resolved now by taking your code as the starting point. Thanks again.

Comment: Good to hear. Happy PDF-ing :)